Python 3.13 with free-thread is slow
I was trying this new free-thread version of the interpreter, but find out that it actually takes longer than the GIL enabled version. I did observe that the usage on the CPU increase a lot for the free-thread interpreter, is there something I misunderstand about this new interpreter?
Version downloaded: python-3.13.0rc2-amd64
Code:
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from random import randint

import time


def create_table(size):
    a, b = size
    table = []
    for i in range(0, a):
        row = []
        for j in range(0, b):
            row.append(randint(0, 100))
        table.append(row)
    return table


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.perf_counter()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(4) as pool:
        result = pool.map(create_table, [(1000, 10000) for _ in range(10)])
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(end - start, *[len(each) for each in result])

python3.13t takes 56sec
python3.13 takes 26sec
python3.12 takes 25sec


Seems related: https://discuss.python.org/t/about-free-threading-performance/54604 "The free-threaded build currently has the specialising, adaptive interpreter introduced in Python 3.11 switched off. This was necessary because the specialising adaptive interpreter is not currently threadsafe. Unfortunately this leads to a significant slowdown for single-threaded code." ... "you may have to wait for Python 3.14"

Perhaps this is an issue specifically with ThreadPoolExecutor, as ThreadPool from multiprocessing.pool reportedly can take advantage of no GIL.

This actually appears to be a multifaceted issue involving shared state with randint. Changing from random import randint to from random import SystemRandom and initialising a random object in each thread fixes this issue.

Python 3.14.0a1 is already released

@toyotaSupra I can't see any changes to free threading in the 3.14.0a1 docs, so the fixes for single threaded performance aren't in yet.

It worked for me.

The primary culprit appears to be the randint module, as it is a static import and appears to share a mutex between threads. Another problem is that you're only able to process 4 tables at a time. Since you want to create 10 tables in total, you'll be running batches of 4-4-2.
Here is the code with the randint problem addressed by replacing it with a SystemRandom instance per thread:
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from random import SystemRandom

import time


def create_table(size):
    a, b = size
    table = []
    random = SystemRandom()
    for i in range(0, a):
        row = []
        for j in range(0, b):
            row.append(random.randint(0, 100))
        table.append(row)
    return table


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.perf_counter()
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(4) as pool:
        result = pool.map(create_table, [(1000, 10000) for _ in range(10)])
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(end - start, *[len(each) for each in result])

And here is some code that achieves the same thing, but is more flexible with the thread creation and avoids unnecessary inter-thread communication:
import threading
from random import SystemRandom

import time


def create_table(obj, result: list[list[int]]):
    a, b = obj
    print(f"Starting thread {threading.current_thread().name}")
    random = SystemRandom()
    result[:] = [[random.randint(0, 100) for j in range(b)] for i in range(a)]
    print(f"Finished thread {threading.current_thread().name}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.perf_counter()
    obj = (1000, 10000)
    results: list[list[list[int]]] = []
    threads: list[threading.Thread] = []
    for _ in range(4):
        result: list[list[int]] = []
        thread = threading.Thread(target=create_table, args=(obj, result))
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
        results.append(result)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
    print([len(r) for r in results])
    end = time.perf_counter()
    print(end - start)

